# Can I use dll in Turbo C++ program and do we have any dll for lzw compression and decompression

Tags: c++, dll, turbo-c++, lzw

I was trying to create a lzw compression program. But i need to finish it by today itself so i want to use some dll for taking my input as txt file and output to as a text file. I want to do this in **TURBO C++** code which are doing my remaining functionalities.
Can anyone suggest me some method.

Comment: Are you using the not-to-outdated 2006 version or the entirely-utterly-outdated DOS version from 1994?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libzip isn't LZW (it uses an algorithm that's generally better), but it is probably the best standard answer.  I don't know if there's a downloadable DLL for it in a standard location, so you might have to compile it from source.

Alternatively, a bit of Google-searching (on "lzw compression dll") found this C++ source code for doing LZW compression, which you may be able to use: http://zabkat.com/blog/24Jan10-lzw-compression-code.htm

Answer (score 0):

this is an oldie question.

You can still look around the LHArc sources on the old Simtel archives. There's an implementation of LZW algorithm before it was patented by Compuserve.